# Filtration on commutative algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, graded-rings, graded-algebras

Given a unital associative commutative algebra $A$ with over a ring/field K, with a filtration, i.e. collection of vector subspaces $0=F_0 \subset F_1 \subset ... \subset F_n = A$ such that $F_m \cdot F_n \subset F_{m+n}$, is it true that the associated graded algebra $\mathcal{G}(A)$ is isomorphic to $A$ as an **algebra?** Does the answer depend on whether K is ring/field?

Comment: Please make things clear, what are the "subspaces", which is the base ring/field, which is the (unit and the) multiplicative structure on the graded object, please also provide some examples showing thus the own thoughts. What happens for instance in the case of upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrices with one non-trivial filtration step given by diagonal matrices?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I made an edit. Well, the upper triangular 2x2 matrices are not commutative algebra, hence not a subject of my question.

Comment: This looks excellent, take time to write an own answer, i would be glad to vote it! Let us now take the example of $0\subset 2\Bbb Z/4\subset \Bbb Z/4$.